# Photo viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, photography, image-viewer

I have been using Apple Photos to view my pictures. I have now switched to Android, so I don't want to use Apple Photos anymore. I am exporting all of the photos currently in there and putting them in a folder.

I really like the way Apple Photos is designed so that I can view a preview of all the photos by date when scrolling down.

I am wondering if there is a software like this? I want a software that isn't proprietary like Apple Photos, because Apple stores the photos in a .photolibrary file. Something that could pull images from a folder with all of my pictures. It would be nice if it had a slick interface, too.

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 on your computer ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10's built-in photo viewer is a lot like Apple Photos.
You can have a look at Faststone Image Viewer, but it's folder based rather than a continuous scrolling view. If you can find old version of Picasa it is a really useful photo viewer too.

Comment: Faststone  is definitely worth a look at (also, their screen capture s/w (Google for the last free version))

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the Metadata such as GPS Location or camera make and model, try XNView MP.
https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp.php